# Pie Chart Image : How To Highlight A Segment On Hover Using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have been given a PNG image of a pie chart as illustrated below.

Is it possible to use CSS to highlight a segment of the pie chart when the mouse hovers over it? I have seen other examples that create an SVG pie chart and use CSS for the [segment hover effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57283811).

In  my  case I would like to apply the hover effect for a given image. Is this possible using CSS or would it be easier to use image maps?

[image: pie_chart]

Comment: You should ask your customer/graphic designer to send a vector based file - ideally svg (you could also convert a pdf to svg). It's most certainly created in an application like Adobe Ilustrator - so the vector data should exist somewhere. If it's a stock illustration - the image provider might also offer a vector version.

Comment: Ok, many thanks, appreciated. Once I get svg I can map it to css classes similar to http://jsfiddle.net/bcdxmpyc/ right?

Comment: Exactly, you might need to tweak you svg e.g adding IDs for click event handling - but it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is easier to use a well-constructed svg file like this:

```css
#Livello_1{width: 500px;}

/*Verde*/
#verde:hover .cls-8{fill: yellow;}
    
/*Blu*/
#blu:hover .cls-3{fill:red;}
    
/*Azzurro*/
#azzurro:hover .cls-2{fill: green;}
    
/*Viola*/
#viola:hover .cls-9{fill: blue;}
    
/*Rosso*/
#rosso:hover .cls-11{fill: orange;}
    
/*Giallo*/
#giallo:hover .cls-10{fill:violet;}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><svg id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 660.66 661.95"><defs><style>.cls-1{letter-spacing:0em;}.cls-2{fill:url(#Sfumatura_senza_nome_4);}.cls-3{fill:url(#Sfumatura_senza_nome_8);}.cls-4{letter-spacing:0em;}.cls-5{letter-spacing:0em;}.cls-6{font-family:MyriadPro-Regular, 'Myriad Pro';font-size:29.11px;}.cls-7{letter-spacing:0em;}.cls-8{fill:url(#Sfumatura_senza_nome_12);}.cls-9{fill:url(#Sfumatura_senza_nome_16);}.cls-10{fill:url(#Sfumatura_senza_nome_27);}.cls-11{fill:url(#Sfumatura_senza_nome_22);}</style><linearGradient id="Sfumatura_senza_nome_8" x1="347.13" y1="189.82" x2="656.18" y2="189.82" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#1382e1"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#0731ff"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="Sfumatura_senza_nome_12" x1="352.71" y1="470.44" x2="660.66" y2="470.44" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#67c30c"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#b7bb16"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="Sfumatura_senza_nome_16" x1="180.24" y1="507.83" x2="480.79" y2="507.83" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#c10c98"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#8317bb"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="Sfumatura_senza_nome_22" x1="4.48" y1="472.14" x2="313.52" y2="472.14" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#fa3d4f"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#fc1377"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="Sfumatura_senza_nome_4" x1="179.87" y1="154.12" x2="480.42" y2="154.12" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#14dddc"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#088fff"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="Sfumatura_senza_nome_27" x1="0" y1="191.51" x2="307.95" y2="191.51" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#fc9c06"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#e7e219"/></linearGradient></defs><g id="blu"><path class="cls-3" d="m347.13,322.59l309.04-6.7s-2.03-83.77-42.59-147.92c-40.56-64.14-110.2-110.93-110.2-110.93l-156.26,265.54Z"/><text class="cls-6" transform="translate(480.42 241.5)"><tspan class="cls-1" x="0" y="0">D</tspan><tspan x="19.5" y="0">e</tspan><tspan class="cls-7" x="34.09" y="0">v</tspan><tspan class="cls-5" x="47.8" y="0">elop</tspan></text></g><g id="verde"><path class="cls-8" d="m352.71,346.55l170.82,257.63s69.72-46.48,102.26-115.05c32.54-68.56,34.86-152.42,34.86-152.42l-307.95,9.84Z"/></g><g id="viola"><path class="cls-9" d="m328.67,353.71l-148.44,271.14s73.6,40.06,149.43,36.92c75.83-3.13,151.12-40.13,151.12-40.13l-152.12-267.94Z"/><text class="cls-6" transform="translate(313.52 571.67)"><tspan x="0" y="0">Ok</tspan></text></g><g id="rosso"><path class="cls-11" d="m313.52,339.37l-309.04,6.7s2.03,83.77,42.59,147.92c40.56,64.14,110.2,110.93,110.2,110.93l156.26-265.54Z"/><text class="cls-6" transform="translate(121.99 431.18)"><tspan x="0" y="0">Ops</tspan></text></g><g id="azzurro"><path class="cls-2" d="m331.98,308.24L480.42,37.1S406.82-2.96,330.99.17c-75.83,3.13-151.12,40.13-151.12,40.13l152.12,267.94Z"/><text class="cls-6" transform="translate(297.49 119.32)"><tspan class="cls-1" x="0" y="0">D</tspan><tspan x="19.5" y="0">emo</tspan></text></g><g id="giallo"><path class="cls-10" d="m307.95,315.41L137.12,57.78s-69.72,46.48-102.26,115.05C2.32,241.39,0,325.25,0,325.25l307.95-9.84Z"/><text class="cls-6" transform="translate(506.68 431.18)"><tspan class="cls-4" x="0" y="0">H</tspan><tspan x="19.27" y="0">i</tspan></text><text class="cls-6" transform="translate(86.91 241.18)"><tspan x="0" y="0">Hello</tspan></text></g></svg>
```

This solution is completely custom, I created a svg file with illustrator, exported and put your svg file in your favorite code editor, view it from browser and inspect it for css classes; after that it's all about css, i hope I have been helpful to you.

Comment: Hi many thanks, ok got it. Yep, so the approach is similar to that in the comments above. I get an svg representation of my image and then will do as suggested to inspect the css classes and then use css. Many thanks again!